# Как передать параметры одной формы в другую?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

У меня есть окно где я вписываю данные об продукте.
Есть кнопка которая открывает маленькое окно с подсчетом всех элементов, которые мы ввели.
В маленьком окне выводит название продукта, сума веса продукта и его цену.

Пытаюсь вывести сумму, например массы продукта - получаю ошибку, что пайтон не может перевести `string`  во `float`, либо я что-то не так делаю.

Подскажите как правильно передать все значения в другое окно? Так же интересно как и другие элементы передать в другое окно.

Пример кода:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QDialog,
                         QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
import sys


class CreateCalc(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window, **kwargs)
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(250, 230)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Create Calculation')

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)

        self.prod = QLabel('Name of product: ', self)

        self.prodEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.prodEdit.move(100, 8)
        self.prodEdit.resize(80, 20)

        self.ingredients = QLabel('Ingredients: ', self)
        self.ingredients.move(80, 20)

        self.Edit1 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))

        self.weight1 = QLabel(' weight:', self)
        self.weight1.move(92, 42)

        self.Edit2 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit2.move(135, 49)

        self.cost1 = QLabel('cost:', self)
        self.cost1.move(176, 42)

        self.Edit3 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit3.move(205, 49)

        self.Edit4 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))

        self.weight2 = QLabel('weight:', self)
        self.weight2.move(95, 68)

        self.Edit5 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit5.move(135, 75)

        self.cost2 = QLabel('cost:', self)
        self.cost2.move(176, 68)

        self.Edit6 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit6.move(205, 75)

        self.Edit7 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))

        self.weight3 = QLabel('weight:', self)
        self.weight3.move(95, 94)

        self.Edit8 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit8.move(135, 101)

        self.cost3 = QLabel('cost:', self)
        self.cost3.move(176, 94)

        self.Edit9 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit9.move(205, 101)

        self.Edit10 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))

        self.weight4 = QLabel('weight:', self)
        self.weight4.move(95, 120)

        self.Edit11 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit11.move(135, 127)

        self.cost4 = QLabel('cost:', self)
        self.cost4.move(176, 120)

        self.Edit12 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit12.move(205, 127)

        self.Edit13 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))

        self.weight5 = QLabel('weight:', self)
        self.weight5.move(95, 146)

        self.Edit14 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit14.move(135, 153)

        self.cost5 = QLabel('cost:', self)
        self.cost5.move(176, 146)

        self.Edit15 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit15.move(205, 153)

        self.Edit16 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))

        self.weight6 = QLabel('weight:', self)
        self.weight6.move(95, 172)

        self.Edit17 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit17.move(135, 179)

        self.cost6 = QLabel('cost:', self)
        self.cost6.move(176, 172)

        self.Edit18 = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(35, 20))
        self.Edit18.move(205, 179)

        self.button = QPushButton('Calculate')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.dialog.exec)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.prod, 0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ingredients, 1, 0, alignment= Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Edit1, 2, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Edit4, 3, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Edit7, 4, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Edit10, 5, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Edit13, 6, 0, alignment= Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Edit16, 7, 0, alignment= Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button, 8, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(10, 1)

        #self.result = int(float(self.Edit2.text() + self.Edit5.text() + 
    self.Edit8.text() + self.Edit11.text() + self.Edit14.text() + 
   self.Edit17.text()))

    def calculate(self):
        #self.button.clicked.connect(self.result)
        self.close()

class Dialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, **kwargs)
        self.main = root
        self.setWindowTitle('Result')
        self.resize(250, 100)
        #self.CC = CreateCalc()

        self.namep = QLabel('Name of your product: ')
        self.nameEd = QLineEdit()
        self.weigLb = QLabel('Weight of your product: ')
        self.weigEd = QLineEdit()
        #self.weigEd.setText()
        self.costLb = QLabel('Cost of your products: ')
        self.costEd = QLineEdit()
        self.butCl = QPushButton('Close')
        self.butCl.clicked.connect(self.closeW)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.namep, 0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.nameEd, 0, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignRight)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.weigLb, 1, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.weigEd, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignRight)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.costLb, 2, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.costEd, 2, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignRight)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.butCl, 3, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(5, 1)

    def closeW(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CreateCalc()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

То что вы хотите сделать, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QDialog,
                             QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QDoubleSpinBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QSize


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, text, sumWeight, sumCost):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Result')
        self.resize(250, 100)

        self.nameEd = QLabel(text)
        self.weigLb = QLabel('Вес вашего продукта: ')
        self.weigEd = QLabel("{:16.4f}".format(sumWeight))
        self.costLb = QLabel('Стоимость ваших продуктов: ')
        self.costEd = QLabel("{:14.2f}".format(sumCost))
        self.butCl  = QPushButton('Закрыть окно Result')
        self.butCl.clicked.connect(self.closeW)

        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow('Название вашего продукта: ',  self.nameEd) 
        layout.addRow('Вес вашего продукта: ',       self.weigEd) 
        layout.addRow('Стоимость ваших продуктов: ', self.costEd) 
        layout.addRow(' ', self.butCl)        

    def closeW(self):
        self.close()


class CreateCalc(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widgets = []
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.prod        = QLabel('Name of product: ', self)
        self.prodEdit    = QLineEdit(self, placeholderText="Введите название продукта")
        self.ingredients = QLabel('Ingredients: ', self)
        self.btnCreateIngredients = QPushButton('Создать/Очистить  `Ingredients`')
        self.btnCreateIngredients.clicked.connect(self.createIngredients)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.prod,        0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.prodEdit,    0, 1, 1, 4)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ingredients, 1, 0, alignment= Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btnCreateIngredients, 1, 1, 1, 4)

    def calculate(self):

        sumWeight, sumCost = 0, 0
        for _, weight, cost in self.widgets:
            if float(weight) and float(cost):
                sumWeight += weight
                sumCost   += cost

        self.dialog = Dialog(self.prodEdit.text(), sumWeight, sumCost)   

        self.dialog.exec() 

    def createIngredients(self):
        if self.prodEdit.text():
            self.widgets = []
            for i in range(2, 7):
                self.editName   = QLineEdit(self, maximumSize=QSize(80, 20))
                self.editName.textChanged.connect(lambda text, i=i-2: self.editNameChanged(text, i))
                self.weight     = QLabel(' weight:', self)
                self.editWeight = QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=0, 
                                                 maximum=9999,
                                                 decimals=4,
                                                 minimumWidth=80)
                self.editWeight.valueChanged.connect(lambda v, i=i-2: self.valueChangedWeight(v, i))

                self.cost       = QLabel('cost:', self)
                self.editCost = QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=0, 
                                                 maximum=9999,
                                                 decimals=2,
                                                 minimumWidth=80)    
                self.editCost.valueChanged.connect(lambda v, i=i-2: self.valueChangedCost(v, i))                                                 

                self.widgets.append(['', 0, 0])
                self.grid.addWidget(self.editName,    i, 0)
                self.grid.addWidget(self.weight,    i, 1)
                self.grid.addWidget(self.editWeight,    i, 2)
                self.grid.addWidget(self.cost,    i, 3)
                self.grid.addWidget(self.editCost,    i, 4)          

            self.button = QPushButton('Calculate')
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.button,    i+1, 1, 1, 3)

    def valueChangedWeight(self, v, i):
        self.widgets[i][1] = v

    def valueChangedCost(self, v, i):
        self.widgets[i][2] = v

    def editNameChanged(self, text, i):
        self.widgets[i][0] = text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CreateCalc()
    window.resize(250, 230)
    window.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
    window.setWindowTitle('Create Calculation')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!