# PyQt5. Как сделать главное окно недоступным при вызове дочернего

Tags: python, pyqt5

Долго пытался сделать родительское окно недоступным для действий и всяких нажатий, пока открыто дочернее. Какими способами можно это осуществить?

Comment: Просто наследуете дочернее окно от `QDialog` и устанавливаете его модальным по отношению к родительскому.

Comment: Вы можете это пронаблюдать здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969146/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E/969357#969357